# Unable to unwrap present

Tags: dota-2

Long long ago, I received a present from Dota. These presents were given every 5 levels I believed, and contained a handful of items (some skins, tools etc).

Some time ago, Dota changed its leveling system I believe* At the time, I was over level 20, as I'd opened my level 20 present and had been given my level 25 present. I am now level 25 in the new system, and attempting to open my present; however, it doesn't allow me: I'm told

> Your Dota Profile isn't high enough level yet

Which is clearly incorrect, as I'm the right level (unless I need to be a level higher, but that's vague). In saying that, I ***just*** got to level 25, so perhaps it needs longer to realise? I don't remember ever having to wait to open my other presents.

Can this present still be opened? If not, what purpose does it serve? Why wouldn't they just remove it when they updated their levelling system, or update the message given?

#### The present:

[image: Level 25 present]

#### My Dota 2 profile, to prove I'm high enough level:

[image: Dota profile]

#### The message I'm given upon trying to open it

[image: Error message]

* <sub>I'm not exactly an *avid* player so I don't really follow much of what's going on. This is all just speculation.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the reborn update retired presents (above lvl 9) can´t be opened anymore.

[source](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Present)

Comment: I believe this is because it is much, much easier to level up the new experience trophy system compared to the old battle point level system.

Comment: Ah, Reborn! That was the update I was thinking of, but couldn't remember what it was called. I knew there were big changes sometime in the past. The site lists it as a _Known bug_ however, and shouldn't the present just be removed from my inventory, or at least provide a useful message (e.g. "Since Reborn, these presents are no longer available for unwrapping"). Surely this is not something Valve would overlook.

Comment: @Tas since this is only a slight inconvienience i suppose they will fix that in the next patch. Also a tip for next time, just google it. I don´t even play Dota and it took me less than a minute to find ;)